# Embedding Documents Directly in Documents with mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to  to bulk insert the array of embedded documents to an existing document. I have tried the below code, but it was not working

```
 arr_loc = []
 arr_loc << Location.new(:name=> "test") << Location.new(:name=> "test2")
 biz = Business.first
 biz.locations = arr_loc
 biz.save # not working
```

currently i am inserting each doc separately by looping the array, i hope there is a better cleaner way to do this.

from mongo shell we can easily do this like this

```
> var mongo = db.things.findOne({name:"mongo"});
> print(tojson(mongo));
{"_id" : "497da93d4ee47b3a675d2d9b" , "name" : "mongo", "type" : "database"}
> mongo.data = { a:1, b:2};
{"a" : 1 , "b" : 2}
> db.things.save(mongo);
> db.things.findOne({name:"mongo"});
{"_id" : "497da93d4ee47b3a675d2d9b" , "name" : "mongo" , "type" : "database", "data" : {"a" : 1 , "b" : 2}}
>
```

check the [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating+Data+in+Mongo#UpdatingDatainMongo-EmbeddingDocumentsDirectlyinDocuments) for more info.. is it possible to do this with mongoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem in calling save method after assignment

```
 biz.locations = arr_loc  #this is fine
 biz.save # no need for that
```

Mongoid updates the document on the assignment itself, no explicit save required. Refer this [mongoid google group thread (Thanks Nick hoffman)](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/440e0ca3b642d5ba) for more info